# Failed to load vite config when running firebase emulator

Tags: javascript, vite, firebase-tools

I'm trying to run a cloud firestore web codelab and I'm stuck at step 4 - https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firestore-web#4

When I try to run the emulator I get the following error:
[image]

I tried several things such as updating node to the latest version, updating vite, adding the path to the config file in the emulators:start command, deleted the node_modules and ran npm i, etc

Here's the vite.config.js code for reference:

```
// import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite/DefineConfig';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
});
```